# Get data from a popup window

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport-google-oauth

I'm authenticating my users via google sing in api. I open the popup with `window.open()`, like this:

```
<button @click="signIn('/google')" class="btn">Sign in with Google</button>

signIn(provider) {
      const strWindowFeatures =
        "toolbar=no, menubar=no, width=600, height=700, top=100, left=100";
      window
        .open(this.baseUrl + provider, "Google", strWindowFeatures)
    }
```

My server authenticates the google info and then responds with the cookie to the popup like this:

```
router.get('/success', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.cookies)
})
```

How can I get the JSON in the parent window (the main app, not the popup)?

Comment: If that successful login has created a cookie, you can simply read it from the main app at any point after, afaik.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for answering. How do you do that? Don't you have to send back the cookie to the client so it can store it?

Comment: The mechanism is this: the server adds a "Set-Cookie" header to the response, and the browser parses and stores the cookie (this happens automatically). Your code sends back `req.cookies`, which implies that the request is already sending along the cookies, so *if* that response does send back the cookies successfully, they are already stored in the browser anyway.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for your patience; as you can see I'm pretty much a noob haha. I thought that you had to send them specifically to your web app and manage them there. My bad. So, on the next http request, should I include the cookies as a header or will the be automatically added?  I put a middleware to inspect the req object but I don't see any cookie in it. Thanks again Chris.

Comment: You're using passport, so after the login was successful, just keep calling `passport.authenticate(...)` in your middleware and you should be set. I guess you can simply redirect or reload on the client after the login window closes and should be authenticated from there on out.

Comment: Chis, unsurprisingly, you were right. The cookie is there after the popup is closed, now I have to deal with it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice, I wasn't 100% sure :)

Answer (score 0):

The main app and its popup can communicate through `Window.postMessage()`.

Here is an example of a main.html page, opening a popup.html page.

`main.html` :

```
<button id="opener">Open popup</button>
<script>
  document.querySelector("#opener").addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.open("popup.html", "_blank", "popup");
  });

  window.addEventListener(
    "message",
    (event) => console.log("event received: ", event),
    false
  );
</script>
```

`popup.html`:

```
<button id="send">Send</button>
<script>
  document
    .querySelector("#send")
    .addEventListener("click", () =>
      window.opener.postMessage("hi there !", document.location.href)
    );
</script>
```

References :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage